# Interface Barcode Scanner MT2000 (Windows CE) with Java Web application

Tags: java, web-services, web-applications, windows-ce, motorola

A client is asking for an integration between a Web application and a barcode scanner. I'm trying to determine the plausibility of this project. If anyone has any experience with this kind of integration please leave your comments, they will be very much appreciated.

**Basic Description**
I have a JSF Web app which already uses this scanner ([MT2000](http://www.motorola.com/web/Business/Products/Bar%20Code%20Scanning/Bar%20Code%20Scanners/General%20Purpose%20Scanners/MT%202000/_Documents/Static%20Files/MT2000-Series-Spec-Sheet.pdf)) to read codes. 
I have two basic processes:

- **Reception**: The codes are scanned and a flag (`isInWarehouse`) is set to true. This flag indicates the code has entered the warehouse.
- **Returns**: The codes are scanned and the `isInWarehouse` flag is set to false to indicate the code is no longer in the warehouse.

Now, what I need is to send a message to the scanner in case of error so that a pop up (or something similar) prevents the user from continuing scanning until he checks what went wrong.

For example in the returns process, if the code scanned is not in the warehouse (i.e, `isInWarehouse == false`), my JFS Web app should send a message to the scanner and a pop up should be shown in the scanner's interface preventing further scanning.

My basic idea would be to:

Publish a Webservice in the scanner (Windows CE 5.0) so that my JSF app consumes it when an error ocurrs. Once the webservice is consumed the application in the scanner would block the scanner interface and show the pop up with the error message, with a button to unlock the screen and be able to continue scanning.

There are some questions:

**Question 1**: 
The scanner uses the [STB20XX cradle](https://docs.symbol.com/manuals/11731201c.pdf?userId=37) which is connected to the computer via USB port, so the scanner sends the codes to my JSF application through the cradle.

Is it possible to comunicate my application direcly with the scanner or it has to be done through the cradle? As far as I understand, the cradle doesn't provide any way to interface with my JSF web application. So I guess the scanner should have to be configured in some way as to be in the same network segment as my app, so that my app can consume the web service published in the scanner.

**Question 2**: 
The scanner & Windows CE docs say that Windows CE 5.0 and the Microsoft .NET Compact Framework support web services, also the [device's specs](http://www.motorola.com/web/Business/Products/Bar%20Code%20Scanning/Bar%20Code%20Scanners/General%20Purpose%20Scanners/MT%202000/_Documents/Static%20Files/MT2000-Series-Spec-Sheet.pdf) (pg. 3) say it supports wireless communication.
Is this enough to make sure I can interface the scanner and my web app through a web service?

Once again any useful comment will be appreciated, Thanks!